# Vista Enterprise doesn't find logon servers in a network with 802.1x authentication

Tags: windows-vista, samba, radius, 802.1

In a network with 802.1x configuration and a samba server configured in the domain, I have a radius server that delegates the authentication against the samba domain for users (using LDAP). The radius defines which VLAN the user is supposed to have access.

I'm trying to put a Windows Vista Enterprise in the same network, but it attempts to logon the domain before authenticating against the network in 802.1x and it doesn't find any logon servers.

In the radius logs I see the machine trying to authenticate with 'host/'. Does Vista enterprise require that I put it in a network with access to the logon server at that point?

Thanks in advance,
João Miguel Neves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Vista requires that the host is authenticated and put on a network with access to the domain's logon servers.